# In Laravel 5.3 Eloquent how to retrieve 3rd table data with where condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 Models(each associated with a table separately) which associated with each other I have attached the table structure below
[image]

Models are,
Doctor Model associated with `doctor_profile_master`

```
<?php

namespace App\TblModels;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Doctor extends Model
{
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'DOCTOR_PROFILE_MASTER';

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'doctor_profile_master_id';

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['doctor_id', 'user_master_id', 'doctor_first_name', 'doctor_last_name', 'doctor_isactive'];


/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function hospitalDoctorAssociateMasters(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\TblModels\HospitalDoctorAssociateMaster','doctor_profile_master_id');
}

}
```

`HospitalDoctorAssociateMaster` Model associated with `hospital_doctor_associate_master`

```
<?php

namespace App\TblModels;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HospitalDoctorAssociateMaster extends Model
{
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'HOSPITAL_DOCTOR_ASSOCIATE_MASTER';

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'hospital_doctor_associate_master_id';

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function doctor(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\TblModels\Doctor','doctor_profile_master_id');
}

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function hospital(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\TblModels\Hospital','hospital_profile_master_id');
}
}
```

`HospitalDoctorRecurringSchedule` Model associated with `hospital_doctor_recurring_schedule`

```
<?php

namespace App\TblModels;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class HospitalDoctorRecurringSchedule extends Model
{
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'HOSPITAL_DOCTOR_RECURRING_SCH_MASTER';

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'hospital_doctor_recurring_sch_master_id';



public function hospitalDoctorAssociateMaster(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\TblModels\HospitalDoctorAssociateMaster','hospital_doctor_associate_master_id');
}

}
```

Thing i want to do is,
How to retrieve the `hospital_doctor_recurring_sch_master` table data using `specific doctor_id`(doctor_profile_master)

I tried some methods but cant able to retrieve those values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
$hospitalDoctors = HospitalDoctorRecurringSchedule::with(['hospitalDoctorAssociateMaster', 'hospitalDoctorAssociateMaster.doctor', 'hospitalDoctorAssociateMaster.hospital'])->all();
```

To search by fields in related tables:

```
$hospitalDoctors = HospitalDoctorRecurringSchedule::with([
                      'hospitalDoctorAssociateMaster', 
                      'hospitalDoctorAssociateMaster.doctor', 
                      'hospitalDoctorAssociateMaster.hospital'])
                      ->whereHas('hospitalDoctorAssociateMaster.doctor', function ($query) use ($doctorId) {
    $query->where('doctor_id', '=', $doctorId);
 })
->all();
```

For `hospitalDoctorAssociateMaster.hospital`:

Define Hospital Model and try

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but here i wanted to check those values with doctor id using where condition

Comment: I've edited my answer, Can you please check? I tried with: 

`$products = Design::with(['design', 'design.categories', 'design.subCategories'])
                ->whereHas('design.categories', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('id', '=', 2);
                })
                ->all();` 

and its working